# Change size table name in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I would like to make uppercase and lowercase for name of Table in Oracle but I have got problem with searching table in Toad and also find table in PL-SQL.

```
Create Table "Test" ()
```

Have you got idea how fix this problem?

Comment: select * from "Test"

Comment: I understand but I would like to search some like this -> "select * from Tekst" we convert application from MSSQL database to Oracle.